# My database allows data that is not in the dropdown list, how do I fix this?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2007

I have a lookup field in my database and I want it to only allow you to input data that is in the lookup list and nothing else. Is there a validation rule I must add to do this?

Comment: Set the `Limit to List` property to **True**

Comment: Thank you very muhch for helping me, Matt Donnan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my earlier comment so that you mark the question as resolved:

Set the `Limit to list` property to **True**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the possible values of a table column, you can create a table for these values (the lookup table) and create a relation between the two tables with referential integrity enforced. The lookup table can then be used as `RowSource` for list boxes and combo boxes.

```
Main Table
----------
id (PK)
some other fields
value_id (FK) <-----+
                    |
Lookup Table        |
------------        |
value_id (PK) <-----+
value text
```

Typically, the main table will only hold the ID of the value in a `Long Integer` field and the lookup table will use an `AutoNumber` field for this ID. A combo box does a good job in looking up the text corresponding to an ID. The advantage of a lookup table is that you can add, remove and change values easily without modifying the application. If you edit a text corresponding to an ID, this change will automatically be visible for all records in the main table referring to this ID.